# If then Statements in HTML Speech Recognition

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a html voice assistant, and I'm struggling with the if/then statements. Here's what I have so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Input area -->
    <p id="output">Output:</p>
    <label for="Argon">Argon</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="speechToText" placeholder="Say a Command" onclick="record()">
    <button type="button" onclick="record()">Start Listening</button>
    <button type="button" onclick ="record()">Stop Listening</button>
    <!-- Below is the script for voice recognition and conversion to text-->
    <script>
        function record() {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.lang = "en-GB";

            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                // console.log(event);
                document.getElementById('speechToText').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            }

            recognition.start();

        }
if transcript = "hello"; {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "YESSS";
              }
    </script>
    <!-- end of script -->
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I could not find a way to get the text converted from the speech recognition into if/then statements. For example, if I were to say "hello" in the speech recognition, the javascript would see "hello" and in the code it would run back "hello user" or something. How could I do this. If someone could give me an answer, this would be EXTREMELY helpful, as then I could just keep adding commands. I've been stuck on this for quite a while now, so it would be great if someone could please help. Again, here is the portion I'm working on:

```html
    <script>
        function record() {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.lang = "en-GB";

            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                // console.log(event);
                document.getElementById('speechToText').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            }

            recognition.start();

        }
if transcript = "hello"; {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "YESSS";
              }
</script>
```

This is my first post here, so I'm new to this community, so I hope that I posted this question correctly and clearly. Thanks :)

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax is erroneous, and if you check your browser's developer console you'll see that.

Comment: [JavaScript if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- Your if statement has a syntax error. `if (condition == true)` is the correct syntax in javascript. See the [W3Schools Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- Your `transcript` is not defined. Based on what you described, I think you would like to nest it into the `onresult` event, which fires once a word or phrase is being recognized.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Input area -->
    <p id="output">Output:</p>
    <label for="Argon">Argon</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="speechToText" placeholder="Say a Command" onclick="record()">
    <button type="button" onclick="record()">Start Listening</button>
    <button type="button" onclick ="record()">Stop Listening</button>
    <!-- Below is the script for voice recognition and conversion to text-->
    <script>

        function record() {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.lang = "en-GB";
            recognition.start();


            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                let transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                if (transcript === "hello") {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "YESSS";
              }
                document.getElementById('speechToText').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            }

        }

    </script>
    <!-- end of script -->
</body>
</html>
```

If you say "hello", you should see:
[image: result]